# Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events is enabled but doesn't work

Tags: activities

My [Activity Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities_enable_shared_activities.htm&type=5) shows that `Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events` is enabled

[image]

Yet the UX doesn't permit me to relate multiple Contacts to an Event or Task - only a single Contact.

Nor am I even given the option of adding the `Name` related list on the Page Layouts for Tasks and Events.

> To show related contacts on event and task detail pages, ensure that the Name related list is included on event and task page layouts. The items in the Name related list aren’t fields, so they don’t adhere to field-level security settings.

- I note that the field `EventRelation.IsParent` is not visible and that is indicative that Shared Activities was not enabled (despite what the UX says).
- I note that `TaskRelations` related list on `Task` is not visible in SOQL

It is as if the feature isn't really enabled. How do I fix this? You can't toggle it off/on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you have to pick up the (metaphorical) phone and contact SFDC Support.

After

- Proving to the Support Team that despite allegedly enabled, the feature doesn't work
- Proving to the next level of the Support Team the same

It will be escalated to senior engineers and after you give permission to roll back the feature,

> Rolling back the shared activities feature is destructive in nature, and some DATA LOSS will occur if the feature has been used before it is rolled back. Specifically, all tasks with more than one related contact will lose all relationships with contacts except the primary contact. (Contact records are not deleted; only the relationships between task and contact are lost.)

Then, upon confirmation from SFDC Support, you can then enable the feature and it works fine.

Support stated that feature is enabled on orgs by default but sometimes the "backend" enablement doesn't "work". The Multiple Contacts for Tasks/Events has been a feature since Summer 12. Not sure when it became a default.